# bank account ownership verification from an IBAN

Tags: finance

In a hypothetical scenario, an employee of a company A that makes eight digit annual income writes on an invoice IBAN of his bank account instead of the company IBAN. How can a different company B verify that the IBAN on the invoice belongs to the company A?

my ideas: they can make a $1 transaction first, but that could have a 5 days delay.. is there a quicker way?

Jurisdictions: USA, EU.

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way would be to write (or to phone) the company switchboard, ask to be connected to accounting (if the employee is not in accounting) or legal (if the employee is in accounting) or the CEO (for extreme amounts) and ask for confirmation that the IBAN belongs to the company. Find the phone number from public sources.

Comment: A bank cannot provide information about a bank account owner?

Comment: How is this a legal question? This is a fairly common fraud scenario, but AFAIK asking about practical fraud prevention tips (or other crime mitigation tips) is off-topic

Comment: I doubt that EU DSP2 and privacy laws would allow a bank to give any information to anyone